# Unclosed linestring to polygon works with QGIS but not with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, openstreetmap, ogr, osmosis

Just like the title, I am extracting OSM riverbank and a lot of riverbanks in OSM is in 'unclosed' linestring.

This is the original river shape i extracted from OSM
[image]

In order to polygonize the linestring, I tried to use ST_MakePolygon (or Polygonize); yet, it says the linestrings are not closed and it cannot make polygons in some areas.

```sql
select st_makepolygon(st_makevalid(shape)) as shape from asia_waterway_line where waterway ='riverbank'
and st_isclosed(shape)
```

[image]

However, I just ran with QGIS Polygonize tool in vector tool and it gives me a polygon that I want to make.

[image]

Polygonize of GRASS, SAGA brought me weird polygon (I'm just giving you other trials that I tried)
[image]

Because all my data are stored in postgresql, I really do want to make them working using PostGIS Spatial Query.
I tried with someone's ST_ForceClosed function but it didn't work either.
Is there any ways that I can solve this issue?

I extraxcted waterway using osmosis tag info and imported them using ogr2ogr.

Comment: From the GRASS output, it looks like the river is made of two lines (well, more than that, but most importantly more than 1 line running around both sides of the river). You could try unioning all the lines of a river, then transforming this one line into a polygon.

Comment: I tried that. Unioning (dissolving) all the lines and convert them to Polygon. the results remained same.

Answer (score 2):

Try enforcing closed *LineString*s by adding their `ST_StartPoint` to the end of the them:

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon( ST_MakeValid( ST_AddPoint( shape. ST_StartPoint( shape ) ) ) ) AS shape
FROM   asia_waterway_line
WHERE  waterway ='riverbank'
;
```

If you want to make sure you are not duplicating points for when a *LineString* is already closed, run:

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon( ST_MakeValid( ST_AddPoint( shape. ST_StartPoint( shape ) ) ) ) AS shape
FROM   asia_waterway_line
WHERE  waterway ='riverbank'
  AND  NOT ST_IsClosed(shape)
UNION ALL
SELECT ST_MakePolygon( ST_MakeValid( shape ) ) AS shape
FROM   asia_waterway_line
WHERE  waterway ='riverbank'
  AND  ST_IsClosed(shape)
;
```

I guess that custom *ST_ForceClosed* function ought to be doing the same, though?

Comment: It won't have the desired effect if each side of the river has its own line

Comment: @JGH definetely good to mention that. sounds like OP has a single *LineString*, though, or the question needs clarification. the multiple lines case is sth. else entirely...